# Trying to execute karate framework UI Automation on apline linux image, however facing error while launching chromium-browser

Tags: docker, gradle, karate, alpine-linux, headless

Trying to execute karate framework UI Automation on apline linux image, however facing error while launching chromium-browser
Basically its being executed through gradle command which works fine on Windows where chrome is installed. But on apline-linux I get following error:

```
    21:41:38.427 [Test worker] DEBUG karate.org.apache.http.impl.conn.PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager - Connection leased: [id: 2][route: {}->http://localhost:9222][total available: 0; route allocated: 1 of 5; total allocated: 1 of 10]
    21:41:38.427 [Test worker] DEBUG karate.org.apache.http.impl.execchain.MainClientExec - Opening connection {}->http://localhost:9222
    21:41:38.427 [Test worker] DEBUG karate.org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultHttpClientConnectionOperator - Connecting to localhost/127.0.0.1:9222
    21:41:38.428 [Test worker] DEBUG karate.org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultManagedHttpClientConnection - http-outgoing-2: Shutdown connection
    21:41:38.428 [Test worker] DEBUG karate.org.apache.http.impl.execchain.MainClientExec - Connection discarded
    21:41:38.428 [Test worker] DEBUG karate.org.apache.http.impl.conn.PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager - Connection released: [id: 2][route: {}->http://localhost:9222][total available: 0; route allocated: 0 of 5; total allocated: 0 of 10]
    21:41:38.428 [Test worker] ERROR com.intuit.karate - karate.org.apache.http.conn.HttpHostConnectException: Connect to localhost:9222 [localhost/127.0.0.1] failed: Connection refused, http call failed after 4 milliseconds for url: http://localhost:9222/json
    21:41:40.429 [Test worker] DEBUG com.intuit.karate.shell.Command - attempt #3 waiting for http to be ready at: http://localhost:9222/json
    21:41:40.430 [Test worker] DEBUG karate.org.apache.http.client.protocol.RequestAddCookies - CookieSpec selected: karate
    21:41:40.430 [Test worker] DEBUG karate.org.apache.http.client.protocol.RequestAuthCache - Auth cache not set in the context
```

Just want to understand what all things need to be installed on the docker to get pass this error, and just to validate when I run ping localhost command, that also does not work, it seems something is not correct on the image itself, any pointer/help would be appreciated, Thanks!
Regards,
Swapnil

I tried to install chromium & chrome-driver on alpine image, and using that custom image tried to launch gradle command to invoke karate ui-automation, it fails with below error:
[Test worker] ERROR com.intuit.karate - karate.org.apache.http.conn.HttpHostConnectException: Connect to localhost:9222 [localhost/127.0.0.1] failed: Connection refused, http call failed after 4 milliseconds for url: http://localhost:9222/json

How to make this work, to run the test automation in headless mode, thanks!

Comment: I don't think chrome works on alpine, or at least I don't have experience with it, so I can't help. the docker image that many teams use with karate is this one: https://github.com/karatelabs/karate/wiki/Docker - that said, we welcome contributions and research on how to make more variations

Comment: Thanks Peter, yes you are right chrome is not supported on alpine, hence I'm trying with chromium only.

Comment: Before actual error about connection one critical message from the error snippet is as following in my opinion : DEBUG com.intuit.karate.driver.chrome_1668743588158 - Failed to move to new namespace: PID namespaces supported, Network namespace supported, but failed: errno = Operation not permitted
    03:53:08.368 [chrome_1668743588158] WARN com.intuit.karate.shell.Command - exit code was non-zero: 133 - [/usr/bin/chromium-browser, --remote-debugging-port=9222,